# How to combine two conditions in a query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
select 
    Cust_code, Cust_Name, Cust_City
from
    mgen_custcode
where
    Mgen_branch = '$bangalore'
        AND Cust_Name like '%$q%'
        or Cust_code like '%$q%'
order by Cust_Name
```

but everytime it shows all the entries be it bangalore or hyderabad or chennai in column Mgen_branch

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City 
from mgen_custcode 
where Mgen_branch='$bangalore' 
      AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') 
order by Cust_Name
```

It will check Cust_Name or Cust_code

**AND** Mgen_branch

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked. I will make this as answer. Ty

Comment: Its been a pleasure, my friend.